# Stuck trying to createFile inside a specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I was hoping someone could help me with something (probably simple) that I'm stuck on.

I have a basic script which outputs each row of a spreadsheet as a separate text file. I'm using createFile to do that, and it's working fine so far. Except - I just can't work out how to make Google Scripts save the text files in a specific folder, only ever in the root. The closest I have managed to get is to create a folder, but even then I can't get the file into it (and I don't want to create a folder every single time of course).

I'm sure it's straight forward but I can't quite get my head round any of the examples I've found elsewhere. Thanks in advance.

Code below:

```
function processSheets() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18QHevoo0TjldkjsbvljkhaljhbdFILdMNLIHEVrKsg");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sheet);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() - 1; //Get number of rows, then use to set last row to fetch


// Fetch the range of those cells
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
// Fetch values for each row in the range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var jobnumber = row[0]; // First column
    var jobname = row[1]; // Second column




    // Make friendly name by concatenating job number and job name with a space in between
    var friendlyname = jobnumber + " " + jobname


    // Create a text file with the job name as file name and content
    DriveApp.createFile(friendlyname, friendlyname);



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the Id of Google Drive Folder:

```
function createFile(id) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  folder.createFile(name, content);
}
```

If you know the name of the folder and not the name.

```
function createFile(folderName) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).getNext();
  folder.createFile(name, content);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for taking the time to reply. Note for others who need this - it took me a while to realise that the ID of the folder needs to be in " quotes.

Answer (score 0):

For now, it has been changed to `.next()` instead of `.getNext()`